# How to set a Range variable using .Find?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I'm trying to set a range variable "rcell" equal to the range of a cell containing the value of variable "lot" by using the `.Find` function.

I want to search in a specific range (column D) instead of all cells.

I get a type mismatch error.

I tried using "Columns(4)" instead of "Range(D:D)".

```vb
Workbooks("lotworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
lot = Cells(row, 3)
Workbooks("findworkbook.xlsx").Activate
Sheets(3).Select
            
Dim rcell As Range
Set rcell = Range("D:D").Find(What:=lot, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 'this is the line with issues'
            
If rcell Is Nothing Then

Else

' ...
```

Expected results: Find cell with the value of variable "lot" in a certain sheet and find that value on another sheet, and set range variable "rcell" equal to that cell location.

Actual results: Type mismatch error. This was working with `Cells.Find` but not with `Range("D:D").Find`.

Comment: Where is `row` defined?

Comment: @Warcupine Still getting a type mismatch. Cells.Find was working, but after I adjusted it to only search in Range("D:D"), I'm getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad row is defined earlier in the code as an integer. The code was working fine before I changed it to only search in Range D

Comment: yeah I always forget without the set it defaults to ```.value``` my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *believe* the issue is `After:=ActiveCell` - remove this and try again:

```
Dim rcell As Range
Set rcell = Range("D:D").Find(What:=lot, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False) 'this is the line with issues
```